# Images do not load from apache redirects from hostname to cname

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, vaadin

I have a web app created using spring boot/Vaadin and apache(2.4 version).
Both apache and the spring boot app are present on the server with hostname - server1.domain.com and the CNAME - server.com.

Spring boot is present at port 4411 and apache port is 4410.

When I hit server1.domain.com:4410, the images in my web app load fine.

Also I can access the image directly by hitting the image URL.

However if I hit server.com:4410, the images do not load and I get a 403(Forbidden) error.

This is the virtual host section of my http.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:4410
<VirtualHost *:4410>
    ServerName server1.domain.com
    ServerAlias server.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://127.0.0.1/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1/"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/cert.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Please help.

Comment: If you are accessing over SSL you need to make sure that the SSL Certificate SAN is configured for the name of ```server.com``` A simple test is to try accessing it over non-SSL if you have that option of course. If non-SSL works, you know for sure where the issue lies.

Comment: Disabling SSL and accessing also gives the same error

Comment: You're `ProxyPass`ing to port 80 (`http://127.0.0.1`), not 4411 (`http://127.0.0.1:4411`). And you don't state what you expect to run on port 80 not returning an error.